# AssertionError in keras while model Fitting

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am getting the following error:

```py
    Epoch 1/15
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-8-08aa5a9ec3b3> in <module>()
         13                 validation_data=[X_test, X_test],
         14                 callbacks=[keras_utils.TqdmProgressCallback()],
    ---> 15                 verbose=0)
    
    5 frames
    /content/tqdm_utils.py in __init__(self, iterable, total, **kwargs)
         10         self.iterable = list(iterable) if iterable is not None else None
         11         self.total = len(self.iterable) if self.iterable is not None else total
    ---> 12         assert self.iterable is not None or self.total is not None
         13         self.current_step = 0
         14         self.print_frequency = max(self.total // 50, 1)
    
    AssertionError:
```

While running the following piece of code:

```py
    s = reset_tf_session()
    
    encoder, decoder = build_pca_autoencoder(IMG_SHAPE, code_size=32)
    
    inp = L.Input(IMG_SHAPE)
    code = encoder(inp)
    reconstruction = decoder(code)
    
    autoencoder = keras.models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=reconstruction)
    autoencoder.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adamax' )
    
    autoencoder.fit(x=X_train, y=X_train, epochs=15,
                    validation_data=[X_test, X_test],
                    callbacks=[keras_utils.TqdmProgressCallback()],
                    verbose=0)
```

I'm on **Tensorflow version 1.15.2 and keras version 2.3.1**
The code is from a coursera assignment which I am running on **Google Colab**.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? Else, please can you share reproducible code to replicate your issue. Thanks!

Comment: The error was still there when I last ran it. But sadly, I don't have the code now. It was an elective course which I was just exploring.

Comment: Not a full resolution, but a workaround: remove the callbacks call - the assertion is in tqdm_utils (used to show a progressbar in output for each epoch) - if you want to output progress without the progressbar, use verbose=True instead.